# How to make images INLINE to each other

Tags: html, css, image

Yes, there are many ways online and I have tried them but for some reason, it doesn't work.

Here is the original code.

```
<!-- AD1 -->
[mycred_link amount="1" href="http://adfly/1LwMem" target="_blank"]

<img id="adfly1" src="http://bdeas.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/AD1.jpg" alt="ad1" width="80" height="80" />

[/mycred_link]
<script>
  $( "#adfly1" ).click(function() {
    $( "#adfly1" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
  });
</script>
<!-- AD1 -->

<!-- AD2 -->
[mycred_link amount="1" href="http://adfly/1M03Vs" target="_blank"]

<img id="adfly2" src="http://bdeas.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/AD2.jpg" alt="ad2" width="80" height="80" />

[/mycred_link]
</a>
<script>
  $( "#adfly2" ).click(function() {
    $( "#adfly2" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
  });
</script>
<!-- AD2 -->

<!-- AD3 -->
[mycred_link amount="1" href="http://adfly/1M04A6" target="_blank"]

<img id="adfly3" src="http://bdeas.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/AD3.jpg" alt="ad3" width="80" height="80" />

[/mycred_link]
</a>
<script>
  $( "#adfly3" ).click(function() {
    $( "#adfly3" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
  });
</script>
<!-- AD3 -->
```

I want to make these 3 images be in one row. I have tried -->

```
display:inline-block
```

but it didn't seem to work. Please help!

Yes, the adfly isn't linked, but thats stackoverflow.

HELP!

Comment: Is there any extra wrap around images, generated by shortcode? Check it with developer tools.

Comment: try float:left on img

Comment: tried and didn't work @VMcreator

Comment: can you show us your code? or perhaps you cam make a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:

```
<!-- AD1 --> 
<div class="fl_lt">[mycred_link amount="1" href="http://adfly/1LwMem" target="_blank"] <img id="adfly1" src="http://bdeas.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/AD1.jpg" alt="ad1" width="80" height="80" /> [/mycred_link] 
<script>
  $( "#adfly1" ).click(function() {
    $( "#adfly1" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
  });
</script> 
</div>
<!-- AD1 --> 

<!-- AD2 -->
<div class="fl_lt"> 
[mycred_link amount="1" href="http://adfly/1M03Vs" target="_blank"] <img id="adfly2" src="http://bdeas.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/AD2.jpg" alt="ad2" width="80" height="80" /> [/mycred_link] </a> 
<script>
  $( "#adfly2" ).click(function() {
    $( "#adfly2" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
  });
</script> 
</div>
<!-- AD2 --> 

<!-- AD3 --> 
<div class="fl_lt">
[mycred_link amount="1" href="http://adfly/1M04A6" target="_blank"] <img id="adfly3" src="http://bdeas.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/AD3.jpg" alt="ad3" width="80" height="80" /> [/mycred_link] </a> 
<script>
  $( "#adfly3" ).click(function() {
    $( "#adfly3" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
  });
</script> 
</div>
<!-- AD3 -->
```

Css code:

```
.fl_lt {float:left;width:33%}
```

Comment: It didn't work before because I did't make the <div> go all the way down to the script but only the IMG.